# Cannot pass special characters to an NSTask

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, special-characters, nstask, nsstringencoding

In Cocoa, I would like to pass a string containing special characters to an NSTask as arguments, however the task does not get the proper string.

```
NSString *city=@"Zürich"; // This is the string with a special character
[arguments addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"-iptc:city=%@",city]];

NSTask *task=[NSTask new];
[task setLaunchPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"exiftool"]];
[arguments addObjectsFromArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-L",@"-overwrite_original_in_place",@"filename", nil]];

[task setArguments:arguments];
[task setStandardOutput:[NSPipe pipe]];

[task launch];
```

The task does not get Zürich as argument but ZuÌˆrich. Any idea how to properly pass strings with special characters ? I've tried UTF8String but without success. Thanks.

Comment: Which encoding does "exiftool" expect for its arguments? Does it work if you execute the same command from the command line?

Comment: From the command line the result is perfect, ie it proper receives and parses 'Zürich'

Comment: I tried this code with the `/bin/echo` command and it reproduces the string "Zürich" correctly. (meaning I used `[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/echo"]`)

Comment: So any idea how to have exiftool interpreting correctly the ü ?

Comment: Actually I misinterpreted a test. The command line parsing does NOT work neither... and found the issue. Was a wrong argument (-L) that I had to remove. Thanks !

Comment: @LaurentCrivello if that solved your problem you should post it as an answer and accept it. Otherwise you'll bleed reputation points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -L argument in exiftool was forcing Latin characterset. Removing it made it work properly.